# How do I transform io::Result into anyhow::Result?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm starting with this working code:

```rust
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Result};
use std::path::Path;

fn read_lines<P, I: IntoIterator<Item = P>>(files: I) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<String>>
where
    P: AsRef<Path>,
{
    let handles = files.into_iter().map(|path| File::open(path).unwrap());
    handles.flat_map(|handle| BufReader::new(handle).lines())
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let lines = read_lines(env::args().skip(1).collect::<Vec<String>>());
    for line in lines {
        println!("{:?}", line?)
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

I need to integrate this into a codebase that is heavily reliant on the `anyhow` library, but I have no idea how I can massage the `BufReader::lines` return value inside the `flatmap` into a `impl Iterator<Item = anyhow::Result<String>>`.

As a reproducible example of where I'm stuck, I integrate `anyhow` into my test bed with this `Cargo.toml`,

```
[package]
name = "rust-playground"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Charles"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
anyhow = "1"
```

And I replace the import of `std::io::Result` with `anyhow::Result`. I'm unsure where to place `with_context` calls, everything I've tried has led to compiler errors.

This attempt fails because I can't use `?` inside the closure, but how else can I "unwrap"? I'm not allowed to use `unwrap` in this context, I'm expected to return an `anyhow::Result`, somehow...

```
use anyhow::{Context, Result};
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::path::Path;

fn read_lines<P, I: IntoIterator<Item = P>>(files: I) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<String>>
where
    P: AsRef<Path>,
{
    let handles = files.into_iter().map(|path| {
        File::open(path).with_context(|| format!("opening path: {}", path.as_ref().display()))?
    });
    handles.flat_map(|handle| BufReader::new(handle).lines())
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let lines = read_lines(env::args().skip(1).collect::<Vec<String>>());
    for line in lines {
        println!("{:?}", line?)
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

And the error message:

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a closure that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `Try`)
  --> src/main.rs:13:10
   |
12 |       files.into_iter().map(|path|
   |  ___________________________-
13 | |                   File::open(path).with_context(|| format!("opening path: {}", path.as_ref().display()))?);
   | |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
   | |___________________|_____________________________________________________________________________________|
   |                     |                                                                                     this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`                                                     
   |                     cannot use the `?` operator in a closure that returns `File`
   |
   = help: the trait `Try` is not implemented for `File`
   = note: required by `from_error`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<FlatMap<Map<<I as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, [closure@src/main.rs:12:24: 13:97]>, std::io::Lines<BufReader<File>>, [closure@src/main.rs:14:22: 14:61]> as Iterator>::Item == std::result::Result<String, anyhow::Error>`
 --> src/main.rs:7:58
  |
7 | fn read_lines<P, I: IntoIterator<Item = P>>(files: I) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<String>>
  |                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::io::Error`, found struct `anyhow::Error`                                                     
  |
  = note: expected enum `std::result::Result<_, std::io::Error>`
             found enum `std::result::Result<_, anyhow::Error>`
```

I can figure out a way to make this compile if my method handles on a single filename:

```
fn read_lines<P>(filename: P) -> Result<io::Lines<io::BufReader<File>>>
where
    P: AsRef<Path>,
{
    let file = File::open(&filename)
        .with_context(|| format!("opening filename: {}", filename.as_ref().display()))?;
    Ok(BufReader::new(file).lines())
}
```

But this doesn't generalize properly to the the case of handling multiple filenames, since `File::open(&path).with_context(...)?` is not correct inside the iterator.

Comment: *I should use the anyhow library* - as an author of a competing library, I disagree that anyhow should be the only or default choice in the matter.

Comment: Your code states you are returning an `anyhow::Result` as your iterator item, but you attempt to return `BufReader::lines`, which returns `io::Result`. Where are you performing the transformation?

Comment: Indeed, an edit has been made, whether it's a better question is questionable, I'm very confused...

Answer (score 3):

The last snippet you provided for handling single files doesn't seem to be returning the same thing as the previous examples.

If you want to just extend the single file example for multiple files, then you could just map the single-file function over the list of files.

Something like this

```rust
fn read_lines<P, I: IntoIterator<Item = P>>(files: I) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<std::io::Lines<BufReader<File>>>>
where
    P: AsRef<Path>,
{
    
    files.into_iter().map(|filename: P| {
        let file = File::open(&filename)
            .with_context(|| format!("opening filename: {}", filename.as_ref().display()))?;

        Ok(BufReader::new(file).lines())
    })
}
```

But if you would like the function to return a `Result<String>` instead of a `Result<std::io::Lines<BufReader<File>>>`, you can transform the errors from `io::Error` to `anyhow::Error` like so,

```rust
fn read_lines<P, I: IntoIterator<Item = P>>(files: I) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<String>>
where
    P: AsRef<Path>,
{
    files.into_iter().flat_map(|filename: P| {
        let file = File::open(&filename)
            .with_context(|| format!("opening filename: {}", filename.as_ref().display()));

        file.into_iter().flat_map(|file| {
            BufReader::new(file)
                .lines()
                .map(|line| line.map_err(anyhow::Error::from))
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: I am looking to have the same interface as my first snippet. Both of these solutions change the behaviour, the result is intended to be an iterator of lines from all the files. The second example for example concatenates all the lines from each file producing a string without lines breaks.

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that, I didn't really test the 2nd one. I've edited the 2nd snippet to return an iterator of the lines from the files.

Comment: Many thanks, the map_err combinator was a missing link for me, I've gotten a bit further. I'm struggling to find what `file.into_iter` does in the docs though... How can a file yield an iterator of files??

Comment: The `file` is  actually a `Result` in the 2nd snippet. We can iterate over the `Ok` value in a `Result`, just like another any other container. So if the `Result` is an `Ok` value, we `flat_map` over the `Ok` value, turning it into an iterator that iterates the `lines` in the buffer, and if it's an `Err`, we do nothing and just return the iterator.

Comment: You can just use "the other side" of from, since it is reflexive with [Into](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html). The map could be: `.map(|line| line.map_err(Into::into))`